# FreebSD ipfw: using not with multiple addresses

Tags: freebsd, ipfw

Any ideas why this rule won't parse?

`ipfw add 10  deny ip  from \{ not 127.0.0.1 and not 10.12.34.0/24 \} to any 53 out xmit wan0`

ipfw doesn't like and and says: `ipfw: missing ")"`

I've tried other variants, for example, putting the not in front of the brace expression, putting the two IPs in a table and then saying `not table(xyzzy)` and nothing will work.

Is there a way to express this with ipfw?

Comment: Placing `and` inside braces is not valid syntax. Placing `not` in front of braces is not valid syntax. However, placing `not` in front of a `table` declaration should be valid.

Comment: Additionally, sets of alternative match patterns (or-blocks) can be
     constructed by putting the patterns in lists enclosed between parentheses
     ( ) or braces { }, and using the or operator as follows:

           ipfw add 100 allow ip from { x or not y or z } to any **(Citing from ipfw(5) )**

Comment: Exactly, you have used `and`, but the manual only mentions using `or`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments, inside an `{...}` or-block the individual options can only be grouped with *or* conditions.
An *and* condition is implicitely assumed for all the present options, and a *not* condition can be prefixed to any single option.
In the old syntax the rule would be written like this:

```
ipfw add 10 deny ip from not 127.0.0.1,10.12.34.0/24 to any 53 out xmit wan0
```

Alternatively, with the new syntax, which does not require `from ... to`, and instead consists only of a list of arbitrary options:

```
ipfw add 10 deny proto ip not src-ip 127.0.0.1 not src-ip 10.21.34.0/24 dst-port 53 out xmit wan0
```